# Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, android-studio

`{ "records": [ { "id": "rec43JpMrSsSmAoGG", "createdTime": "2022-12-17T15:30:47.000Z", "fields": { "Name": "green." } }, { "id": "recBfJzGGNdwRiCWR", "createdTime": "2022-12-17T15:31:16.000Z", "fields": { "Name": "yellow." } }, { "id": "recDynbN2dibdMLvO", "createdTime": "2022-12-17T15:31:16.000Z", "fields": { "Name": "purple." } }, { "id": "recNZMK3mZda33CXU", "createdTime": "2022-12-17T15:31:16.000Z", "fields": { "Name": "brown." } }, { "id": "reca6MBTrUKQXqcIl", "createdTime": "2022-12-17T15:31:16.000Z", "fields": { "Name": "pink." } }, { "id": "recdM8t7quScDwRLF", "createdTime": "2022-12-17T15:31:16.000Z", "fields": { "Name": "orange." } }, { "id": "recq5aeM3M7Gjsif9", "createdTime": "2022-12-17T15:30:47.000Z", "fields": { "Name": "blue." } }, { "id": "recxcNttZ5UoamShI", "createdTime": "2022-12-17T15:30:47.000Z", "fields": { "Name": "red." } } ] }`

its my Json file but i hew to use Volley laibery but ex. Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONArray
help us
java code is

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://loclhost:1111/json";
         JsonObjectRequest jsonArryRequest =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                 try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.getJSONArray("records").getJSONObject(1));

                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     Log.d("Papa","Ex - "+e.getMessage());
                 }

             }
         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 String errorm = error.getMessage();
                 Log.d("papa", "error : "+errorm);

             }
         });

         queue.add(jsonArryRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing a new jsonArray that's not the way to do it

Instead of this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.getJSONArray("records").getJSONObject(1));
```

Do this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("records");
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1));
```

By doing it this way you will also get your second json object into `jsonObject` variable

Comment: @NAREN BAIRAGi can you please also upvote the answer if it solved your issue